# Can't get the correct Bool result in C#

Tags: c#, validation, boolean-expression

I have a form where I would like to check for validation before processing the form. My form has 2 sections so I want to make sure that at least one item from each section is selected when they press submit button, and if they did then go to Dashboard.aspx. Even if I put all the required info when it checks for result1 and result2, I get false. Result1 and Result2 won't get the correct value. Even if the values are True again it passes false.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;

        bool result1 = false;
        bool result2 = false;
        CheckWireFromValidation(result1);
        CheckWireToValidation(result2);
        if (result1 == true && result2 == true)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/DashBoard.aspx");
        }
    }

    public bool CheckWireFromValidation (bool result1)
    {
        if (drpFromCoporate.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpFromCapital.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpFromProperty.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            result1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result1 = false;
            ShowAlertMessage("You need to choose at least one filed from Wire From drop downs!!");
        }         
        return result1;
    }


    public bool CheckWireToValidation(bool result2)
    {
        if (drpToCapital.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpToCoporate.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpToProperty.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpToTemplate.SelectedIndex != 0 || txtCorpAmt.Text != "" || txtCapAmt.Text != "" || txtPropAmt.Text != "" || txtTempelateAmt.Text != "")
        {
            result2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ShowAlertMessage("You need to choose at least one filed from Wire To drop downs!!");
        }
        return result2;      
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the results of `CheckWireToValidation`. You're using the `false` value you allocate initially.

Try this

```
    bool result1 = false;
    bool result2 = false;

    if (CheckWireFromValidation(result1) && CheckWireToValidation(result2))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/DashBoard.aspx");
    }
```

#### Edit

The behavior you're expecting is that of the [`out` parameter modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx). But please don't write code that way ...

I edited your code to get rid of .. em .. cruft. This should be more readable.

```
protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;

    if (CheckWireFromValidation() && CheckWireToValidation())
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/DashBoard.aspx");
    }
}

public bool CheckWireFromValidation ()
{
    if (drpFromCoporate.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpFromCapital.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpFromProperty.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {          
        ShowAlertMessage("You need to choose at least one filed from Wire From drop downs!!");
        return false;
    }         
}

public bool CheckWireToValidation ()
{
    if (drpToCapital.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpToCoporate.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpToProperty.SelectedIndex != 0 || drpToTemplate.SelectedIndex != 0 || txtCorpAmt.Text != "" || txtCapAmt.Text != "" || txtPropAmt.Text != "" || txtTempelateAmt.Text != "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        ShowAlertMessage("You need to choose at least one filed from Wire To drop downs!!");
        return false;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I hadn't noticed that

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing `Result1` and `Result2` in as parameters instead *assigning* them. The results will never be set.

Here's one correct way of doing this

```
bool result1 = CheckWireFromValidation(result1);
bool result2 = CheckWireToValidation(result2);

if (result1 == true && result2 == true)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/DashBoard.aspx");
}
```

and also a side note. I think we can safely remove the boolean parameter from the `CheckWireFromValidation` methods. Since the return value doesn't depends on the input variable.

Hope this helps.